# Repeatedly losing data sources for raster layers in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster

I have several raster layers that keep losing their data connection whenever I add a new layer from running a tool. I repaired the data source, but this keeps happening every time I run a tool. Is there an option/preference that I need to change so this stops happening? I didn't move any files so the path names are the same.

UPDATE:
I restarted Arc and the document, which seemed to work for a little bit, but after a while it started happening again.

Comment: You're not alone. I ran into this same issue but never figured out why it was happening. I'm following to see if anyone provides an answer.

Comment: What tool(s) with what parameter values are you running?

Comment: Do you have a very long folderpath/file name?

Comment: @PolyGeo I'm running point density on a point shp file (rectangular neighborhood with 1 by 1 map units).

Comment: @whatahitson The pathname might be a bit long, there are several subfolders to keep all the data organized. I got the suggestion to store the data on an external hard drive as a potential solution, but haven't tried that yet.

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.  It sounds like you should move your data to a shorter path as a test.